# How to refresh ImageSlider with when clicking a button?

Tags: android, image-slider

I have an image slider and I get two photos (photo link address) from my server. 
I have also created a button in my activity and I want to click on it to display the replaced photos on the server. 
Photos are replaced when I exit the app and log in again, but I want to reload by clicking the button.

```
ImageSlider imageSliderFirst;
Button btn_ref;

@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


 // init
        imageSliderFirst = findViewById(R.id.slider_first);
        btn_ref = findViewById(R.id.btn_ref);

        //-------------------------
 


List<SlideModel> slideModel1 = new ArrayList<>();
        slideModel1.add(new SlideModel("https://iranhonarbazar.ir/danial/photos/mp_slide.jpg"));
        slideModel1.add(new SlideModel("https://iranhonarbazar.ir/danial/photos/up_slide.jpg"));

        imageSliderFirst.setImageList(slideModel1, true);

 btn_ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // refresh slider ???

                //-------------------------
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an `Adapter` for the `ImageSlider` to manage adding the image to it.

- First thing you going to create an image layout `image_layout.xml`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

- Then you create the adapter

```
public class SliderAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderAdapter.SliderAdapterViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<SliderData> list;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<SliderData> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public SliderAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        // here you going to set by the layout you create
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
        return new SliderAdapterViewHolder(inflate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SliderAdapterViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final SliderData sliderItem = list.get(position);
       // I Use Glide to load the image to the ImageView
        Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                .load(sliderItem.getImgUrl())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    static class SliderAdapterViewHolder extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
        View itemView;
        ImageView imageViewBackground;

        public SliderAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

- now in your `Activity` you can set the `SliderAdapter`  of the `ImageSlider`

```
SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          ...
       
          imageSliderFirst = findViewById(R.id.slider_first);
          btn_ref = findViewById(R.id.btn_ref);

          sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);
          imageSliderFirst.setSliderAdapter(adapter);

          btn_ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  ArrayList<SlideModel> slideModel1 = new ArrayList<>();
                  slideModel1.add(new SlideModel("https://iranhonarbazar.ir/danial/photos/mp_slide.jpg"));
                  slideModel1.add(new SlideModel("https://iranhonarbazar.ir/danial/photos/up_slide.jpg"));

                  adapter.setList(slideModel1)
              }
          });
    }
```